# DomPDF - Bloquear impressão e download

Tags: php, dompdf

É possível bloquear impressão e download no DomPDF?

Comment: Olá Rafael, a resposta lhe ajudou, sobrou alguma duvida em relação a ela?

Answer (score 2):

Não tem como prevenir contra download definitivamente, o que pode fazer é no máximo dificultar, conforme a [resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12266671/1518921) e no [Grupo Google](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/dompdf-dev/IHnFkl7ejXw/wMFWFsNSStcJ)

Você pode usar o CPDF para especificar o que o usuário pode fazer com o documento.

> https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/master/lib/Cpdf.php

De acordo com a documentação do CPDF:

Chamando a função [`setEncryption()`](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/master/lib/Cpdf.php#L2177) você poderá fazer o arquivo ser encriptado, o usuário não vai poder usar copiar, modificar ou imprimir (isto não ao menos nos leitores de PDF mais usados, como Adobe Reader, Foxit e o nativo do Chrome)

```
$cpdf = $dompdf->get_canvas()->get_cpdf();
$cpdf->setEncryption('', '', array('copy', 'print'));
```

Se quiser configurar:

```
$cpdf = $dompdf->get_canvas()->get_cpdf();
$cpdf->setEncryption('usuário', 'senha', array('copy', 'print'));
```

---

Não é possivel bloquear o download, tudo que navegamos mesmo que não ocorra o download propriamente dito na verdade foi baixado para sua máquina em quanto renderizava ou antes de renderizar, talvez você esteja com problema com download automático, isto é padrão para desabilitar você pode ajustar nos parâmetros, usando `'Attachment' => 0`, assim:

- **Versão 0.7**

  ```
  <?php
  use Dompdf\Dompdf;

  require 'vendor/autoload.php';

  $dompdf = new Dompdf();
  $dompdf->loadHtml('<strong>Stack</strong> Overflow');

  $dompdf->render();

  $dompdf->stream('document.pdf', array( 'Attachment' => 0 ));

  //Pra prevenir espaçamentos no final
  exit;
  ```
- **Versão 0.6 ou mais antiga**

  ```
  <?php

  require_once 'dompdf_config.inc.php';

  $dompdf = new Dompdf();
  $dompdf->load_html('<strong>Stack</strong> Overflow');

  $dompdf->render();

  $dompdf->stream('document.pdf', array( 'Attachment' => 0 ));

  //Pra prevenir espaçamentos no final
  exit;
  ```

Ainda sim se o seu problema for o <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> do teclado não há muito o que fazer, no máximo para tentar evitar eu diria que o recomendável para apenas dificultar seria criar um página com o PDF usando iframe e o hash `#toolbar=0` por exemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    *, html, body, .pdf {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="pdf.pdf#toolbar=0" class="pdf"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Isto vai desabilitar o toolbar, o que ajuda um pouco, isto não ao menos nos leitores de PDF mais usados, como Adobe Reader, Foxit e o nativo do Chrome com disse anteriormente.